# undefined method ` =' for #<Agency id: nil, name: nil, ip_adress: nil>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing some rspec tests on my app and there is a bug, it show me that error :

```
undefined method ` =' for #<Agency id: nil, name: nil, ip_adress: nil>
```

There is my tests :

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Agency, type: :model do
  it "should create the agency if all fields are filled" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:agency)).to be_valid
  end
  it "should fail if name is missing" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:agency, name: nil)).to_not be_valid
  end
  it "should fail if ip_adress is missing" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:agency, ip_adress: nil)).to_not be_valid
  end
  it "should fail if there is a double name in db" do
    agency = FactoryGirl.create(:agency)
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:agency, name: agency.name)).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

My agency model :

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  module Agencymod
    attr_accessor :name, :ip_adress
  end
  has_many :users
  has_many :incidents
  has_many :field_agency_agencies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :field_agencies, through: :field_agency_agencies

  # # Regexp for the postal code.
  # cp_regexp = /\A((0[1-9])|([1-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])|(2A)|(2B))[0-9]{3}\z/
  # # Regexp for email.
  # email_regexp = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$\z/
  # # Regexp for phone number.
  # phone_regexp = /\A(0|\+33|0033)[1-9][0-9]{8}\z/
  # # Regexp for ip address.
  ip_regexp = /\A(?:(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\z/

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { in: 0..44 }
  validates :ip_adress, presence: true, format: { with: ip_regexp }, length: { in: 0..49 }
end
```

And finally my factory :

```
  factory :agency, class: Agency do |f|
    f.name  { Faker::Address.city }
    f.ip_adress "8.8.8.8"
  end
```

It is the first time this error appear and when I have tested the user model it works very well...

Sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: In what line does that error happen? Please show the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Any specific reason to have `attr_accessor :name, :ip_adress` under the module **Agencymod**. I think taking it out of module should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone post answer. 
I've found the error it appear there are an space between the f.name and the `{ Faker::Address.city }`

When I have removed it, it show me the same error but with `undefined method'name='...` so I writed the factory like that :

```
f.name Faker::Address.city
```

and it works very well ...
My others factories are writted as below :

```
 factory :user do |f|
    f.surname { Faker::Name.first_name }
    f.name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    f.pseudo { Faker::Internet.user_name }
    f.password "password"
    f.email { Faker::Internet.free_email }
    f.type_user_id 23
    f.agency_id 2
    f.tel "0606060606"
    f.ip_addr { Faker::Internet.ip_v4_address }
  end
```

and are working well too ..

```
f.name "TEST" # That works !
f.name"TEST" # Works too
f.name Faker::Address.city # Works
f.name { Faker::Address.city } # Nope
```

Issue in gem ?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. [Dynamic attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#dynamic-attributes) are well supported by factory girl, and I see no reason why that should fail. Are you using an old version of the library? What happens if you remove that `f` variable, like the documentation shows?

Comment: Also, removing whitespace like that should *definitely* make no difference -- so I'm guessing you actually forgot to save the file originally, and were running an older (incomplete) version of the factory definition.